# Applying CSS transform with jQuery using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get the below code working when I don't use the variable. When I add the variable it breaks though.

```
$('.right, .auto_slide').click(function() {
    var slider_margin = parseInt($(this).closest('.slider').css('transform',"translateX"));
    var new_margin = slider_margin - pane_width;
    $(this).closest('.slider').css('transform',"translateX("+new_margin"+)");
});
```

HTML

```
<section class="stage" id="basic">
    <div class="slider" style="transform: translateX(0px);">

        <!-- Content -->

    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the variable like this

```
$('.thing').click(function() {
    var whatever = 20 - 100;
    $('.slider').css('transform',"translateX("+whatever+"px)");
    //                                       ^^like this^^ 
});
```

Also you cant subtract string like that, do 20-100

Comment: I can't get it working. I edited my question with my exact code.

Comment: @Moppy You have a typo `"+new_margin"+)"`the + sign must be outside the quotes like this `"+new_margin +")"`

Comment: Like this? (+"new_margin"+)

Comment: Nope. But nothing is being applied to the element either.

Comment: Ah, I added the "px" and it worked. Still bugs but I'll figure it out. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to change my margin-left to translate in line 2. There's a bug with it, can you spot it?

Comment: Is the value of slider_margin NaN? @Moppy could you post your html markup

Comment: Currently the value is NAN because I'm not grabbing the CSS property correctly. I need to find the current transform, translateX CSS property. I'm not doing it right though and it's throwing an error

Comment: Use this to get the numbers `var slider_margin =parseInt($(this).closest('.slider').css('transform').match(/\d/g).join(""))`

Comment: That gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'join' of null

Comment: Ok I've added it to the question.

Comment: Ah, I can see the problem you were getting at. Sorry :(

Comment: @Moppy .slider element does not have the css attribute transform, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've edited question again. It's still not working. Sorry for wrecking your head mate!

Comment: @Moppy Take a look at this fiddle and try to implement that to your code. http://jsfiddle.net/F9TmW/

Comment: Thanks mate, I appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenation

```
$('.thing').click(function() {
    var whatever = 20 - 100;
    whatever += "px";
               //^ add px
    $('.slider').css('transform',"translateX("+whatever"+)");
                                            //^         ^  
});
```

and you can not subtract string you need numerbs